# odbc_connect() without parameters

Tags: php, odbc

Is there any way we can call odbc_connect() without any parameters in php?
By this i mean is there any way in php.ini to have such settings to set username,password and dsn in advance or any other way?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can create your own configuration file, (e.g. config.php) and another file to hold some standard functions that are used trough out your website.

And then, you create your own function (e.g. aragorn_connect()) which read from the config file and run the odbc_connect() normally. So, next time you need to use the db, you can just call the aragorn_connect() and voilà.

**OR**

you can use one of the framework available online (cakePHP, Yii, cogeigniter etc).